# Incorrect ID value when restarting the spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

I don’t understand the reason why when I restart the application and add a field to the database through a post method, the ID tends to the numbers 52__102__152__202__252, etc.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Cats {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CatColors color;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
    private String catName;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/cats")
public class CatsController {
    @Autowired
    private CatsRepo catsRepo;
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Cats> saveCat(@RequestBody Cats cat){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(catsRepo.save(cat), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @GetMapping("/showAll")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Cats>> showAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(catsRepo.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

[how it looks like in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SIri.png)

i was changing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto in properties, GeneratedValue strategy and remove spring security dependency with class but it seems like it didn't help.

Comment: Just a guess - `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: Thank you it helped,  i had to drop this table once to remove id exception which i had, when i tried different strategies.

Comment: @l_______ What are you expecting? 1,2,3,4,5 maybe? Is that your concern?

Comment: yep, it seemed strange to me that  after restart, the next value of id after 3 become 52